# I want to keep first 2 options and delete remaining in a select element with jquery,

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to delete all options in a select element with jquery, except for the first `n`.
where `n` is amount of options to **keep**.

Comment: delete last n-2 = leave first 2! Isn't it meant delete last 2 or leave n-2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per your conversation you want that except first 2 option others will be removed. Please try below code it will help you::

Assuming `sub_buyer` is your selectbox's **ID**

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('#sub_buyer').find('option').not(':nth-child(1), :nth-child(2)').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name="sub_buyer" id="sub_buyer">
 <option value="1">FB</option>
 <option value="2">RM</option>
 <option value="3">Joey</option>
 <option value="4">Isaac</option>
 <option value="5">Christina</option>
 <option value="6">James</option>
 <option value="7">Armando</option>
 <option value="8">Kent</option>
 <option value="9">Tyler</option>
 <option value="10">Michael</option>
 <option value="11">Dylan</option>
 <option value="12">Ryan</option>
 <option value="13">John-Ralph</option>
 <option value="14">John-Mike</option>
</select>
```

Working jsfiddle url: https://jsfiddle.net/xya0p3ym/

Comment: This is not dynamic though, what if you wanted to keep the first **3**? The author stated he wanted the amount to be dynamic

Comment: Not an issue he can run a loop, according to that make nth value dynamic. The idea is to solve the issue not done OP's job.

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember a way to find the last 2 elements of a collection as a selector but this will do it:

```js
    $('#mySelect')
        .find('option:last-child')
        .remove();
    $('#mySelect')    
        .find('option:last-child')
        .remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="">Select one</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeLast (a){
var arr = $("#select_id option");
for(var i = 0; i<a;i++){$(arr[arr.length-1]).remove();}
};
removeLast(number_of last_items_to_delete);
```

This code selects only option tag, not all children and can remove as many last childs as you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var n = 4;
  var options = $('select').children();

  for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    if (i >= n) {
      options[i].remove();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Why did you take n =4.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you take for n, because the number is dynamic. Wether you keep 1 or 3 this always works.